# Is there any way to debug top down using the UI to step through and target specific code in Visual Studio C# windows forms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a third party UI framework (open source) that hasn't been maintained for a while, so I downloaded the source and added a reference to the project. There is some strange UI behavior and some additional buttons / scrollbars seem to be drawn when using panels and user controls nested inside each other in more complex layouts.

Since I don't know the origin of the code and I now have access to the source of the project I was wondering if the following is possible:

1. Start the debugger
2. Interact with one of the UI controls by hovering over it / clicking it / whatever
3. Initiate a debug flow and step through code somehow? <-- top down, not bottom up like normal when you write your own code

I have never done this before and do not know if it's possible or if anyone has tips and tricks for troubleshooting UI code to try and find UI flaws this way.  I would like to interact with the odd UI components, click them, and try to identify the project's code that is tied to generating it and see if I can fix it.  Otherwise it is like looking for a needle in a haystack searching through code, stepping through stuff that seems to have nothing to do with it looking...

Any insight or debugging techniques from the UI side down into code would be appreicated.

Note: In the designer code there is no issue, it's only during run time when the application is running does this happen

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "top down" and "bottom up" in the context of debugging? The 3-step process you've described is the normal way you do debugging in visual studio (and most other IDEs afaik). If you set the debugger to step through one line at time then it should halt next on the code triggered by the UI element, once you interact with it. Either that or you can do a process of elimination by setting breakpoints on code you suspect might be relevant.

Comment: But to be honest you should be able, if you're using the forms designer, to see what events are hooked up to each element just by examining its properties

Comment: Try to understand the actual layout of windows (HWND) using a tool like Spy++.You won't be able to debug but at least, you will know relation between controls and get some extra information that might be useful. You could also see which windows messages (WM_) are send to a window. That kind of information could be useful to figure out code to look or conditional breakpoint to set.

Comment: If you have a quite compilcated layout that does not works with the library you are using, sometime, it does not worth taking time to debug it. You might consider alternative layout that is simpler and works correctly or using some other components.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the project's code that is tied to UI with my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool.